# Richtext editor coloring

Tags: javascript, focus, rich-text-editor, text-coloring

I am building a cross browser rich text editor. In that i had a scenario like some text will be inserted with a color
For Eg:

Hi {$1} --> internally this {$1} will be <span style="color:red">$1</span>

When place the cursor at the end of {$1} and if I start typing, the characters are getting entered inside that span.

Can anyone suggest an option to set focus outside of that span, So that I wont get the color of the typed text in red?

Answer (score 1):

It's default web-browser behavior so it's hard to override it.

You may re-define whole stuff (incl. cursor, selections, typing, inserting, etc.) via CANVAS and not to use default Editor Mode. But it's very complex way.

So try to insert 1 space after the span:

```
<span style="color:red">$1</span> <!-- see the 1 space after the span -->
```

And when the user will put the cursor after the span, text would not be red.

Comment: Adding a space is a sensible suggestion. Using `<canvas>` is less sensible.